# How do I make a mod for Counter-Strike 1.6 or Half-Life 1?

Tags: steam, mods, counter-strike, half-life, goldsrc-engine

Is there a boilerplate mod that I can download? Can I separate the mod folders from the game folders so that it's easy to keep track of what content I added? What kind of formats are the content stored in and how can I edit them? What kind of scripting/programming is used?

I wasn't able to find any resources for this via Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the games on Steam.

**In order to create mods for Counter Strike 1.6 and/or Half-Life, you can use the Half-Life SDK**. This set of tools can be downloaded by heading to your *Library* -> *Tools* in Steam, and double-clicking 'Half-Life SDK'.

[image: How to find the Half-Life SDK in Steam]

Once downloaded, in its folder (default `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Half-Life SDK`), you'll find some (at times outdated) documents to get you started.

The SDK packs the map editor Hammer, example maps and models, and tools to create texture archives and sprites, among other things. Concerning the latter, I suggest downloading [NEM's tools](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/), however: they have better GUI's, and are generally easier to use.

- The textures come in .WAD format;
- the maps come in .RMF (uncompiled) or . BSP (compiled) formats;
- sounds come in .WAV format;
- sprites come in .SPR format;
- resources (HUD, menus, other overlays and in-game text) come in .RES format (easily editable with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/));
- game scripts come in .CFG format. **[Here](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=94381) is a good tutorial to get you started, and [here](https://gamebanana.com/scripts/games/4254) are some examples of game scripts.**

Since Counter-Strike 1.6 is in itself a modification for Half-Life, the best way, IMHO, to get acquainted with creating a mod would be to **make a copy of the mod folder** (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Half-Life\cstrike`) and going through the files with the acquired tools. This way you get an idea of the folder structure and the formats used. Counter-Strike is run by the Half-Life executable `hl.exe`, using the parameter `-game cstrike`, this can be substituted by your new folder name.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Sorry that you were downvoted and my question was closed.